# Error during Cloudera installation saying No database server found running on host server

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am doing a cloudera cluster installation with 3 nodes using Installation path C as in Cloudera Documentation. I get option to enter the database name ,user and  password for the databases I had created during the setup on the node with cloudera manager server. On entering the database details I get message "No database server found running on host server".

I created a user account in database in below way:

```
grant all on hive.* TO 'hive'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'hive_password';
```

In the Database host field I entered local host. I got the above error. I also tried entering the full hostname . It still gave the same error.  I also verified the file

```
/opt/cloudera-manager/cm-5.12.2/etc$ cd cloudera-scm-server/db.properties.
```

It also has the host as localhost.

What can be the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "using installation path C"? It looks like you're using Linux. Also, not each server is running a Mysql database on "localhost", so you should be using external addresses

Comment: Thanks. By 'Installation path C', I mean I am following this document: [link]https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/cm_ig_install_path_c.html#cmig_topic_6_7 [/link]

Comment: Also , I followed the steps to configure external database as MySql , I installed it only on the node which has cloudera manager. Also I tried giving FQDN instead of hostname during installation but got same error. The link I followed for external database configuration is  : [link]  https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/cm_ig_mysql.html#cmig_topic_5_5_2  [/link]

Comment: Are you able to connect via `mysql` command to that host using the credentials you made?

Comment: Yes I am able to connect. On the machine with Cloudera Manager, I ran below command and am able to connect:  'code' mysql -u hive -p hive_password /'code'. However the Cloudera Manager screen shows No database server found running on host myFQFN name.

Comment: Installation successfully completed now.  Resolution: When the installation got stopped and it restarted all over once again. I did two things : Disabled firewall by doing iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F   .   The second thing is giving internal IP instead of external IP while adding hosts.   When it got to the stage of giving database passwords I did the same thing as previous time (entered localhost) as the host. This time it worked. Not sure which step actually resolved.  Thanks cricket_007

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer below rather than leave in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Installation successfully completed now. I had tried a lot of things but the below steps got it working:

Resolution: When the installation got stopped and it restarted all over once again. I did two things :

1) Disabled firewall by doing iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT iptables -F .

2) The second thing is giving internal IP instead of external IP while adding hosts. When it got to the stage of giving database passwords I did the same thing as previous time (entered localhost) as the host.

Now during the stage where it asks for password, I did what I was trying before (giving the FQFN as the Host). It worked fine this time and gave no errors.